# Assign id's (1,2,..etc) to a dynamic html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to achieve functionality in the linked picture.

[image]

The table grows as users click on the add button. I'm trying to replace the text inside the first column of the newly added td with the length of the table. I'm new to jQuery and not sure how to do that. Any help would be great.

Comment: What code have you tested ?

Comment: `$('#newTd').text(tableRows.length);` you are going to have to go a bit further before asking for help :)

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to answer you with your code but you can know the added row number with `$('#yourTBodyID > tr').length`

Have a look to this code :

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Zone ID</th>
      <th>Zone Description</th>
      <th><button onclick="addRow();">Add Row</button></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS** :

```
function addRow() {
    var rowNum = $('#tableBody > tr').length + 1;
  $('#tableBody').append('<tr>'
        + '<td>' + rowNum + '</td>'
      + '<td><input type="text"/></td>'
      + '<td><button>Disable</button></td>'
  );
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dcjbo22/)

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'll face a few more problems, more than just showing the number on the recently created `tr`. As you don't write down any code, I'm note sure at which point of the development you are, or which functionalities have you created already. I'll briefly try to explain how to achieve it, just showing you the path.

1. Add button should find in the DOM a valid `<tr>`to `.clone()`. It could be a "seen tr" or a template one. In the first situation you should clean  the information in the input.
2. Once you have saved that cloned node into a variable, you should prepare it for insertion.

   - Counting the `<tr>` lines (it'd help if you have a classname on them) and assign the `.length()` to the first `<td>` using `.text()`
   - Changing name attribute on the input inside the second `<td>`tag. Otherwise when the form is sent to the server, you will loose every input with the same name which prior the last one.
3. On the last `<td>` tag you have a disabled button. It won't have any attached event on your brand new element. You can attach it here, or if you prefer, you can add the event on the very beginning using something like `$('table').on('click','.disable-button',function(e){})`. Doing that instead of `$(.disable-button).click()` will assure you that elements with this class created after DOM `.ready()`fires up will get this event.

I hope it helped you